# ftruncate php csv prevent LF from being removed

Tags: php, csv

i write an array to csv file   using fputcsv in php .
i know that fputcsv writes a empty line as the last out put so my csv looks like

1. apples
2. orranges
3. pear
4. empty last line

What i did to remove the last empty line was use the below code and it works it writes a csv without the last empty line.

```
    $stat = fstat($handle);
    ftruncate($handle, $stat['size']-1);
```

My problem is that it delets the LF code and what than means on the next time i append to my csv  a new value just gets appended to the same line as line 3  in stead of next line because the LF is missing ...

1. apples LF
2. orranges LF
3. pear

anyone know how to fix the above ?

Comment: Just append a new line (`"\n"`)  the next time you are on to something with that file

Comment: You shouldn't have to remove the last newline. Every line should end with a newline, it doesn't create a blank line if you have one after the last line.

Comment: A blank line is when you have *two* newlines in a row.